# How to browse for a text/doc file in Android and the get the path of the file chosen?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I have to a EditView. I need to browse for text/doc files from my file system on Android device to display the path of the file chosen. How can I do that?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("*/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Audio "), SELECT_AUDIO);

Comment: You can search `File browser Android example or source code`.

Comment: This doesn't give me option to select files from data folders. I need something which should direct me to downloads folder or files folder and I should be able to select a file which returns its path. So that I need to upload the file to server

Comment: I need to select the file and then I need to upload it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/Filepicker/filepicker-android) solved my problem. It is a file picker activity in which you will be able to browse for folder and in back you will be returned with the path of the file you selected.