# how to browse only text files from my application

Tags: android

i have built an application,where i am supposed to browse only for txt files in the device and read it.but i am not getting a valid solution to it.Like for example if we take whatsapp,there you can browse different files under different headings like under videos you will only browse videos and under gallery you will only browse images.but whats in case for text files only?is there any way?Please suggest.

Comment: For that you have to write your own filter i.e, you have to check each and every file with extension of .txt then only you have to display.

Comment: i think, this link may help you,

[search doc file:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12925899/how-to-browse-for-a-text-doc-file-in-android-and-the-get-the-path-of-the-file-ch?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try this.

//for example your folder present in sdcard/cts.
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/cts");
for (File wavfile : f.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) 
{
String str = wavfile.getName().toString();
}

//create a class and the filter based on your need file extension
class FileExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return (name.endsWith(".txt") || name.endsWith(".TXT")  );
        }
    }

thank you.
```

Comment: for (File wavfile : f.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) in this line

Comment: i think check your xml file and add manifest file to permission external storage for  write file. it your xml file error. your are accessing unwanted element in your main activity.

Comment: Hey actually in which folder you want to access either internal storage or external??

Comment: @ Sethu..,it works,but it is giving the output Write,y so..??
can you explain me little bit

Comment: the out put of this code will gives files name of the corresponding directory of your sdcard.

Comment: and what i hv to do,to open that file ,so as to read the data from it..??

Comment: see this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22603395/trying-to-open-the-sdcards-txt-file-in-my-edittext/22604658#22604658

Comment: @Sethu i just want to ask 1 more thing,it is returning text file,as per my question,i asked in starting,but when i giving the pdf file or doc file it is returning null..,what changes i have to make to read other files too.??

Comment: you just add this lines to return (name.endsWith(".txt") || name.endsWith(".TXT") || (name.endsWith(".pdf") || (name.endsWith(".doc") );

Answer (score 0):

I would put your directories your searching into arrays... Loop the arrays and look for the file extensions after the " `.` " if its not a text extension remove it. Then display the new array to user like the photo gallery works or however else you would want to represent them. 
Note- If you need access to these later you may want to be saving the path if the user say...needs to click and open them...

you may be able to use something to this effect for searching the SD Card

```
File file[] = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();  
file[i].getAbsolutePath();
```

Then search it for the extensions you want...

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a file manager as you like. Just needs a bit of work around. But definitely helps

```
    //fill method is to get the dir
        private void fill(File f) 
        {
            File[] dirs = f.listFiles();
            this.setTitle("Current Dir: " + f.getName());
            List<Option> dir = new ArrayList<Option>();
            List<Option> fls = new ArrayList<Option>();
            try 
            {
                for (File ff : dirs) 
                {
                    if (ff.isDirectory())
                    {
                        dir.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "Folder", ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                    }
                    else 
                    {
String filetype[] = objOption.getName().split("\\.");
        if (filetype[(filetype.length) - 1].equals("txt"))                                   {   
                        fls.add(new Option(ff.getName(), "File Size: "+ ff.length()+" bytes", ff.getAbsolutePath()));
                                   }
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {}
            Collections.sort(dir);
            Collections.sort(fls);
            dir.addAll(fls);
            if (!f.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("sdcard"))
            {
                dir.add(0, new Option("..", "Parent Directory", f.getParent()));
            }
            adapter = new FileArrayAdapter(FileChooser.this, R.layout.dialog_file_view,dir);
            lvFileList.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```